# Can't retrieve hard disk S.M.A.R.T. data OR Temperature

Tags: hard-drive, sata, temperature, smart

Currently I have two hard disks , both are W.D Blue .

The first one (320GB) shows SMART data correctly along the temperature . that drive is a SATA 2 rev 5 .
the other hard disk (newer one (500GB) is a SATA 3 rev 0 . it's SMART data isn't accessible . also no software can get it's temp.

so I made some google search and found a utility to check if the hard disk support the SMART data .
the utility is called "smartmontools" , and here's a screenshot of result from both hards .after more digging I found that there's something called "updated" which determines when the hard disk updates the SMART data , the 320gb shows an "Always" mode which update the smart data on-time each min or so , while the 500gb uses the offline mode , which make no software can access it's smart data , also another thing , the 500gb hard disk is a SATA 3 which make his peak at 6GB/s but it shows that he operates at a peak of 3GB/s so what controls the speed ? the SATA port on the motherboard or the SATA cable ? may the SATA cable , make the hard disk SMART DATA inaccessible ?

Any help would be great , I just discovered that 320GB disk has a 19% health and he is a dead man walking , so I don't want to take chances with both hard disks .

Screenshots :

[320GB with correct SMART DATA .](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRdkq.png)

[500GB with inaccessible SMART DATA .](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8fys.png)

Comment: SATA speed depends on the drive itself and the controller in the motherboard. If that controller is SATA II, a SATA III drive will operate as a SATA II drive.

Comment: Sounds like a case where the HDD should have the firmware updated.  The drive with the inaccessible S.M.A.R.T data isn't in the program you used.  So the information it is displaying for that drive cannot be trusted.  However, you shouldn't update the firmware, without proper research a backup of the drive.

Comment: @Ramhound Well I made some search on firmware updates too , sadly I found this from WDC site "For Consumer Internal Hard Drives, Mobile and Desktop there are no firmware updates, as the latest Firmware is installed at manufacturing." .